# Inheritance , method signature , method overriding and throws clause

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, throws

My `Parent` class is :

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class Parent {
        int x = 0;
        public int getX() throws IOException{
        if(x<=0){
         throw new IOException();
        }
       return x;
      }
 }
```

I `extend` this class to write a subclass `Child`:

```
public class Child1 extends Parent{
     public int getX(){
        return x+10;
   }
}
```

Notice while *overriding* the *getX* method in the `Child` class , I have removed the `throws` clause from the method definition .Now it results in an anomalous behavior by the compiler which is expected :

```
new Parent().getX() ;
```

does not compile without enclosing it in a `try-catch` block , as expected .

```
new Child().getX() ;
```

compiles without enclosing it in a `try-catch` block .

But the below lines of code needs the try-catch block .

```
Parent p = new Child();
p.getX();
```

As this could be foreseen i.e. using a parent class reference to invoke a child method during run-time polymorphism , why the designers of Java didn't make it mandatory to include the throws clause in the method definition while overriding a particular parent class method ? I mean if a parent class method has throws clause in its definition , then while overriding it the overriding method should also include the throws clause , Ain't it ?

Comment: In your last sentence, did you mean ", then while overriding it the ***overriding*** method (the method in subclass) should also include the throws clause"???

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No, this is appropriate - an overridden method can be more restrictive about what it throws (and returns) because this can be useful for callers who *know* at compile time that they'll be using the overridden method, and don't want to bother with exceptions which can't happen etc. It has to be more restrictive rather than more *permissive* though, so that it can't surprise callers who *do* access it through the parent declaration.

Using the overridden method via a reference of type `Parent` is never going to violate the contract of "it might throw `IOException`" - the absence of an exception doesn't violate the contract. The other way round (if the parent *didn't* declare the exception, but the overriding method does) *would* be a contract violation.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me :)

Comment: `so that it can't surprise callers who do access it through the parent declaration`. This really helped me understand the reasoning.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the overriding method might not throw any exception at all (or at least fewer exceptions), thus you can remove exceptions from the throw clause (or the throw clause as a whole).

Suppose the overriding method catches all exceptions, logs them and returns a special value. Although that's not good style (it would change the semantics of the method) it is still possible andd thus you'd not have to catch exceptions that are never thrown if you know at compile time that you're dealing with a `Child`.

Adding exceptions won't work, since users of the class who access it through the `Parent` reference don't know of any exceptions that `Child` might add.

Answer (score 4):

Easy to remember

1. Access modifier can be changed from restricted to less restricted,
   for example from protected to public, but not vise versa
2. throws signature can be changes from parent exception to child exception class, but not vise versa

This code is valid

```
public class A  {

    protected String foo() throws Exception{
        return "a";
    }

    class B extends A {
        @Override
        public String foo() throws IOException{
            return "b";
        }
    }
}
```

Overrided foo method has public access, not protected and throws IOException that child of Exception

This code is not valid

```
public class A  {

    public String foo() throws IOException{
        return "a";
    }

    class B extends A {
        @Override
        protected String foo() throws Exception{
            return "b";
        }
    }
}
```

Overrided foo method has more restricted access modifier and throws Exception that NOT child of IOException

By the way you can override method from superclass and not throw ecxeptions at all

This code valid

```
public class A  {

    public String foo() throws IOException{
        return "a";
    }

    class B extends A {
        @Override
        public String foo(){
            return "b";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This helps, got destroyed in interview because of this question.

Answer (score 2):

You have the freedom to override a method without the throws keyword, because if you want to develop a method by controlling all the exceptions, then you can do that by overriding the method without any throws clause.

But remember one thing that if you want to include the throws clause in the subclass method, then the throws clause must associate with the exception which must be the same or the subclass of the exception what is thrown by its superclass method. for example-

```
class Super{
    void a()throws IOException{
        ......
    }
}
class Sub extends Super{
    void a()throws IOException{
        ......
    }
}
```

The  a() method of class Sub must throw IOException or any subclass of IOException, otherwise compiler will show error.

That means if you write

```
void a()throws Exception
```

in the class Sub, then it will cause compilation error.