# Why do I have the option to remove the throws clause here even though the interface I inherit from defined it?

Tags: java, exception, cloneable

The interface in question is [`FileVisitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html), which defines this method:

```
FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(T dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
    throws IOException;
```

My really simple implementation is this:

```
public final class FailFastDeletionVisitor
    implements FileVisitor<Path>
{
    private final FileSystemProvider provider;

    public FailFastDeletionVisitor(final Path victim)
    {
        provider = Objects.requireNonNull(victim).getFileSystem().provider();
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(final Path dir,
        final BasicFileAttributes attrs)
        throws IOException // <-- HERE
    {
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    // etc etc    
}
```

At the point marked `<-- HERE` in this code extract, strangely enough, IDEA (since this is my IDE of choice) tells me that declaring that exception is unnecessary...

Since IDEA is not without bugs, I decided to try it out. I removed the exception and it compiled! So, IDEA is right.

And then I recalled that if you implemented `Cloneable` your were not required to throw [`CloneNotSupportedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CloneNotSupportedException.html), which is *also* a checked exception, for your code to compile (not that this is the canonical reommendation, of course). Even though [`Object`'s `.clone()` throws it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--).

And indeed, when you `@Override` clone() and do not declare it to throw `CloneableNotSupportedException`, it still compiles.

BUT.

Then I tried this:

```
final Callable<Void> callable = new Callable<Void>()
{
    @Override
    public Void call()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

`Callable` is supposed to throw `Exception` but so far it compiles; however, if I:

```
callable.call();
```

then this is a compilation error...

What is what?

---

**EDIT** OK, there is a MAJOR difference; `Cloneable` does *not* define `clone()`; `Object` does.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036016/inheritance-method-signature-method-overriding-and-throws-clause: "an overridden method can be more restrictive about what it throws (and returns) because this can be useful for callers who *know* at compile time that they'll be using the overridden method, and don't want to bother with exceptions which can't happen etc. It has to be more restrictive rather than more *permissive* though, so that it can't surprise callers who do access it through the parent declaration."